# Which SQL Update is faster/ more efficient

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to update a table every time a certain action is taken.

**MemberTable**

- `Name varchar 60`
- `Phone varchar 20`
- `Title  varchar 20`
- `Credits int` <-- **the one that needs constant updates**
- etc with all the relevant member columns 10 - 15 total

Should I update this table with:

```
UPDATE Members 
SET Credits = Credits - 1 
WHERE Id = 1
```

or should I create another table called account with only two columns like:

**Account table**

- `Id int`
- `MemberId int` <-- foreign key to members table
- `Credits int`

and update it with:

```
UPDATE Accounts 
SET Credits = Credits - 1 
WHERE MemberId = 1
```

Which one would be faster and more efficient?

I have read that SQL Server must read the whole row in order to update it. I'm not sure if that's true. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this doesn't directly answer the question but I'm going to throw this out there as an alternative solution.

Are you bothered about historic transactions? Not everyone will be, but in case you or other future readers are, here's how I would approach the problem:

```
CREATE TABLE credit_transactions (
   member_id        int      NOT NULL
 , transaction_date datetime NOT NULL
   CONSTRAINT df_credit_transactions_date DEFAULT Current_Timestamp
 , credit_amount    int      NOT NULL
 , CONSTRAINT pk_credit_transactions PRIMARY KEY (member_id, transaction_date)
 , CONSTRAINT fk_credit_transactions_member_id FOREIGN KEY (member_id)
     REFERENCES member (id)
 , CONSTRAINT ck_credit_transaction_amount_not_zero CHECK (credit_amount <> 0)
);
```

In terms of write performance...

```
INSERT INTO credit_transactions (member_id, credit_amount)
  VALUES (937, -1)
;
```

Pretty simple, eh! No row locks required.

The downside to this method is that to work out a members "balance", you have to perform a bit of a calculation.

```
CREATE VIEW member_credit
  AS
SELECT member_id
     , Sum(credit) As credit_balance
     , Max(transaction_date) As latest_transaction
FROM   credit_transactions
GROUP
    BY member_id
;
```

However using a view makes things nice and simple and can be optimized appropriately.

Heck, you might want to throw in a NOLOCK (read up about this before making your decision) on that view to reduce locking impact.

## TL;DR:

**Pros:** quick write speed, transaction history available

**Cons:** slower read speed

Answer (score 1):

Actually the later way would be faster.
If your number transaction is very huge, to the extent where millisecond precision is very important, it's better to do it this way.
Or maybe some members will not have credits, you might save some space here as well.

However, if it's not, it's good to keep your table structure normalized. If every account will always have a `credit`, it's better to include it as a column in table `Member`.
Try to not having unnecessary intermediate table which will consume more space (with all those foreign keys and additional IDs). Furthermore, it also makes your schema a little bit more complex.

In the end, it depends on your requirement.

Comment: +1. Also remember that accoutns will never have longer searches and will have separate locks from the other table- which helps with transaction throughput.

Answer (score 0):

As the ID is the primary key, all the dbms has to do is look up the key in the index, get the record and update. There should not be much of a performance problem.

Using an account table leads to exactly the same access method. But you are right; as there is less data per record, you might more often have the record in the memory cache already and thus save a physical read. However, I wouldn't expect that to happen too often. And well, you probably work more with your member table than with the account table. This makes it more likely to have a member record already in cache, so it's just vice versa and your account table access is slower then.

Cache access vs. physical reads is the only difference, because with the primary key you will walk the same way throgh the ID index and than access one particular record directly.

I don't recommend using the account table. It somewhat blurrs the data structure with a 1:1 relation between the two tables that may not be immediable recognized by other users. And it is not likely you will gain much from it. (As mentioned, you might even lose performance.)

Comment: -1. You totally ignore the fact that 2 tables decouble blocking vdue to locks. Lock granularity ca nbe quite important for permanent updates ina table.

Comment: The Credits need to be updated every time someone clicks a button,  so the members table would see very little action except for logging in and phone / email updates Thanks

Comment: @TomTom: Sorry, I don't get your point. The statement is `UPDATE tablename SET Credits = Credits - 1 WHERE Id = 1` in either case. tablename is either Members or Accounts. One table affected only. I see no different locking scenarios here.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I assume Accounts would have tons of updates - single ID lookups, but the other table would ALSO have searches (by user name for example). This way a search does not block a credit update. When you need scalability tricks like that really help decoupling different operations and in this case "semi static" from "frequently updated" data.